# How do i make my void comiler read a string and print in the MessageBox what is after it?

Tags: c#

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
   {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void compiler()
        {
            String print = "print Hello World";
            String sP = print.Substring(print.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
            MessageBox.Show(sP, "Console");
        }

        private void TB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void runToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            compiler();
        }
    }
    }
```

I tested this out and on start it prints hello world.
now I'm just trying to get it so in the text box it can read that I have typed "print" and whatever is after the space (Ex: "print " < that space right there) it will print the text. I hope that I made it clear enough for you!
So basically it says "print Hello World" and on start (when i debug) it shows a message saying Hello World, now I'm trying to get it to read the text box (TB) and if it says "print" then print whatever is after it.

Comment: So you're asking how to get the text of a TextBox? Did you look at the `.Text` property?

Comment: Well not technically im trying to get the text after "print" whenever i type it into the text box.

Comment: But your code already does that.  What is your question?

Comment: How do i read the text box and if it says print then print what ever is after it, there is nothing in the text box, the text box is blank.

Comment: Ok i see how that works i feel stupid, Thanks guys for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear what you need but this may help?

```
   namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
   {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void compiler()
        {
            String print = TB.Text;
            if (print.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("print ")
            {
              String sP = print.Substring(print.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
              MessageBox.Show(sP, "Console");
            }
        }

        private void TB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            compiler();
        }

        private void runToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            compiler();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Ok i understand know, i forgot about TB.Text :P thanks every one for helping